# Coffeescript Access Function

Tags: javascript, loops, coffeescript

I'm new to coffeescript and had a question about accessing functions.

Given the code below how would I access the checkType function from within the constructor's for loop?

```
class ApplicationForm.Save
  constructor: (@formItems) ->
    @that = this
    for item in @formItems
      do ->
        checkType(item)

   checkType: (forItem) ->
     console.log(@formItem.find("input").length)
```

Comment: Why are you doing `@that = this`? (transpiles to `this.that = this`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a fair bit of confusion here:

1. `@that = this` doesn't make any sense. It looks like you're attempting to reproduce the common JavaScript idiom of:

   ```
   var that = this;
   ```

   so that you can use the desired `this` elsewhere. But `@` isn't used for declaring variables (CoffeeScript does that automatically), `@` is just shorthand for `this.`. You're saying `this.that = this` and that does nothing useful.
2. `do` is used in a loop when you need to immediately evaluate the loop variable rather than just grabbing the reference. The common case is something like this:

   ```
   for i in [0, 1, 2]
     $(".something#{i}").click -> console.log(i)
   ```

   That code would just lead to everything saying `2` regardless of what gets clicked because all the anonymous callbacks are using the same `i` reference. Adding `do` simply wraps the loop body in a self-invoking function to force the loop variable to dereferenced so this:

   ```
   for i in [0, 1, 2]
     do (i) ->
       # do something with `i`...
   ```

   is like this JavaScript:

   ```
   for(i = 0; i <= 2; ++i)
     (function(i) {
       // do something with `i`...
     })(i)
   ```

   You're passing `item` to a function already so the `do` is superfluous.
3. Your `checkType(item)` is trying to call a function that doesn't exist. You seem to want to call the `checkType` method and going back to what `@` is all about, we see that you need to use `@` to call that method on `this`:

   ```
   @checkType(item)
   ```
4. Your `checkType` method has a `forItem` argument but you're using `@formItem` inside the method. But again, `@` is just how we say `this` in CoffeeScript so there seems to be a combination of a typo (`forItem` versus `formItem`) and some confusion about what `@` means. Your `checkType` should probably look like:

   ```
   checkType: (formItem) ->
     console.log(formItem.find("input").length)
   ```

Putting all that together gives us:

```
class ApplicationForm.Save
  constructor: (@formItems) ->
    for item in @formItems
      @checkType(item)
  checkType: (formItem) ->
    console.log(formItem.find("input").length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the fat arrow `=>` in the for loop in order to retain the value of `this` from the constructor:

```
for item in @formItems
  do =>
    @checkType(item)
```

You can read more about the fat arrow syntax in the [CoffeeScript documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow).